# Divide the elements of one column with the corr element of another column

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have an $N\times 2$ matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix}
    a_{11} & a_{12}  \\
    a_{21} & a_{22}  \\
    \vdots & \vdots  \\
    a_{N1} & a_{N2} 
\end{pmatrix}$. What is the cleanest code to make a new $N\times 2$ matrix $B$ with the first column unchanged but second column should consist of elements of second column of $A$ divided by the corresponding element of the first column of $A$. That is $a_{1i}$ divide by $a_{i1}$.

Thus the elements of $B$ should read

$B=\begin{pmatrix}
    a_{11} & a_{12}/a_{11}  \\
    a_{21} & a_{22}/a_{21}  \\
    \vdots & \vdots  \\
    a_{N1} & a_{N2}/a_{N1} 
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: What about `b = {#1, #2/#1} & @@@ a`, clean enough?

Comment: Woah. That's an answer.

Answer (score 12):

```
(*matlab-like approach*)

nRows = 5;
nCols = 2;
(mat = Table[i + j, {i, nRows}, {j, nCols}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
mat[[All, 2]] = mat[[All, 2]]/mat[[All, 1]];
mat // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1 Also: `mat[[All, 2]] /= mat[[All, 1]]`

Answer (score 9):

It's always nice to have a clean method, but if you have large matrix, performance can be an issue. Consider following comparison:

```
a = RandomReal[1, {1000000, 2}];
{t1, r1} = AbsoluteTiming[{#1, #2/#1} & @@@ a];
{t2, r2} = AbsoluteTiming[Transpose@{#1, #2/#1} & @@ Transpose@a];
{t1, t2, r1 == r2} 
(* {1.48458, 0.024882, True} *)
```

The first solution iterates over large index, it makes it way slower, although a little bit more cleaner visually.

Comment: Good demonstration!

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {6, 7}};
```

Using `Cases`

```
b = Cases[{a_, b_} :> {a, b/a}] @ a;

b // MatrixForm
```

[image]

If we want to change `a` inline we can use `ApplyTo` (new in 12.2)

```
a = {{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {6, 7}};

a //= Cases[{a_, b_} :> {a, b/a}];

a // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Grabbing the @eldo's matrix and using `SubsetMap`:

```
a = {{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {6, 7}};

SubsetMap[#/a[[All, 1]] &, a, {All, 2}]

(*{{2, 3/2}, {3, 4/3}, {4, 5/4}, {5, 6/5}, {6, 7/6}}*)
```

Another faster solution is the following:

```
Thread@{#[[All, 1]], Divide @@ Transpose@#} &@a

(*{{2, 3/2}, {3, 4/3}, {4, 5/4}, {5, 6/5}, {6, 7/6}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {6, 7}};
```

```
MapThread[{#1,#2/#1}&,Transpose[a]]

(* {{2,3/2},{3,4/3},{4,5/4},{5,6/5},{6,7/6}} *)
```