# Using Map to convert Feet + Inches to Inches in a List of Lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of list as follows:

```
{{5., 10., "Male"}, {6., 4., "Male"}, {5., 10., "Male"}, {5., 9., \
"Male"}, {5., 7., "Female"}, {6., 0., "Male"}, {5., 11., "Male"}, \
{5., 9., "Female"}, {5., 5., "Female"}}
```

The first two elements of the inner list specify the height of the subject in feets and inches. I would like to convert that to a List of list with just the height in Inches e.g.

```
{{70, "Male"}, {82, "Male"} .....}
```

What is the **Map** way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given

```
data = {{5., 10., "Male"}, {6., 4., "Male"}, {5., 10., 
    "Male"}, {5., 9., "Male"}, {5., 7., "Female"}, {6., 0., 
    "Male"}, {5., 11., "Male"}, {5., 9., "Female"}, {5., 5., 
    "Female"}};
```

You can use `Map` with

```
{12 #[[1]] + #[[2]], #[[3]]} & /@ data

(* {{70., "Male"}, {76., "Male"}, {70., "Male"}, {69., 
  "Male"}, {67., "Female"}, {72., "Male"}, {71., "Male"}, {69., 
  "Female"}, {65., "Female"}} *)
```

A slightly more concise version (suggested by @March) uses `Apply`

```
{12 #1 + #2, #3} & @@@ data

(* {{70., "Male"}, {76., "Male"}, {70., "Male"}, {69., 
  "Male"}, {67., "Female"}, {72., "Male"}, {71., "Male"}, {69., 
  "Female"}, {65., "Female"}} *)
```

And if you'd really like to abuse Mathematica, you can write

```
m = {{12, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}};

Rationalize[data].m
(* {{70, "Male"}, {76, "Male"}, {70, "Male"}, {69, "Male"}, {67,
   "Female"}, {72, "Male"}, {71, "Male"}, {69, "Female"}, {65, 
  "Female"}} *)
```

Comment: Add the `Apply` version to your answer: `{12 #1 + #2, #3} & @@@ list`.

Comment: If you list is really long, you can improve performance by using vector operations: `Transpose@{12 #1 + #2, #3} & @@ Transpose@data`, performance gain can be quite significant as shown [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127626/divide-the-elements-of-one-column-with-the-corr-element-of-another-column/127629#127629)